Blender OSL to HLSL
Is there an addon to convert blenders shaders into shaderes usable by unreal engine/unity?
A code converter/optimizer?
I know about the bake textures and height maps from shaders then just plug into unreal and add roughness/metallic/world offset, I want something that will convert it in code format not in image format.

Are you talking about shaders, materials, or textures, specifically? Can you [edit] and clarify?
